# Rails Custom Tagged Logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

In your Rails config files you can set:

```
config.log_level = :debug
config.log_tags = [:uuid, lambda { |req| Time.now } ]
```

However, this only works when using Rails.logger. I know you can create a custom tagged logger. But the syntax is a little verbose:

```
logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new(STDOUT))
logger.tagged("BCX") { Logger.info "Stuff" }
```

Is there anyway I can configure a custom logger with log_tags, so I don't have to specify which tags to use every time? I'm sure I could create a custom class for this, but is there a built in way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to this Gist, I was able to figure it out:
https://gist.github.com/1278448

I don't even need to use the formatted logger, just had to subclass Logger:

```
class NepcoLogger < Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp.to_formatted_s(:db)} #{severity} #{msg}\n"
  end 
end
```

Comment: How does this do what you want? Does this output a tag like "BCX" in your question?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's not exactly what I asked for, but it still accomplishes the same goal in my case. Primarily I wanted a timestamp. If you know a better answer though, please share.